# PHP json_encode При кодировании "0" получаю пустую строку

Tags: php

Вот мой код:

```
$answer[...]['discountPersent'] = 0;
//$answer['discountPersent'] = intval(0); //и так пробовал
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($answer,  JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Данные для $answer[...]['discountPersent'] беруться из Mysql, массив многомерный.

В ответ выводиться:
"discountPersent":""
Если значение больше нуля, то все отрабатывает корректно.

Как исправить ошибку, чтобы выводилос:
"discountPersent":0

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится, я скопировал ваш код из вопроса и получил `{"discountPersent":0}`

Comment: К сожалению на моем сайте она воспроизводиться(((
Возможно дело в настройках PHP (использую выделенный сервер)?

Comment: Вот прямо так, без всяких mysql, конкретно этот код не выводит у вас ноль?

Comment: нет, никакие настройки РНР не превращают ноль в пустую строку. А вот вы, разумеется, запускаете не этот код, а какой-то другой. Который сократили, "чтобы нам было легче его читать" или там "потому что он ужасно секретный!"

Comment: Код отправки полный а вот сам массив конечно сократил.
Сам массив многомерный с кучей полей.
Если массив взять в том виде что в примере, то все отрабатывает как надо!

Comment: Ну вот значит ошибка находится где-то в том месте, которое вы сократили

Comment: ну вот перед тем как заявлять что "проблема воспроизводится", сначала **выполните именно тот код, который здесь написали**, посмотрите внимательно на результат, а потом подумайте - а что вы вообще хотите спросить-то?

Comment: если до сих пор непонятно, что если json_encode вываодит пустую строку, то в исходных данных **тоже пустая строка**. А откуда она там берётся в ваших данных и после вашего кода - **мы не знаем**.

Comment: Понял, Спасибо, буду искать...

Comment: и вообще отладчик поставь, 95% вопросов отпадет